# $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{x+\cos x}{x+\sin x}$ Show that L'Hôpital's rule gives no answer.

Tags: limits

Compute $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{x+\cos x}{x+\sin x}$$ by common sense. Show that L'Hôpital's rule gives no answer.

I saw this question required the use of common sense. L'Hôpital's rule does not help but how is that supposed to be shown/proved?

Do you have some hints?

Comment: for example, what is the limit of $\frac{x+1}{x-1}$ as $x\to \infty$? Apply the same reasoning here.

Comment: Could you explain. Your example can be solved using L'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: There's a VERY standard procedure to calculate that limit (or more generally limits of rational functions) which doesn't use L'Hopital's rule at all. Just divide by the highest degree term throughout.

Comment: Calculate the limit of $(x+cos(x))/x*x/(x+sin(x)$. Note that $(x+cos(x))/x=1+Cos(x)/x$.

Comment: $\frac{x+\cos x}{x+\sin x}=\frac{1+\frac{\cos x}{x}}{1+\frac{sin x}{x}}$ Calculating the limit as $x\rightarrow\infty$ becomes now a trivial thing, for $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\cos x}{x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}=0$

Comment: @mathx: L'Hospital does not work here since $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1-\sin x}{1+\cos x}$ does not exists as you can see by playing with values $x=(2n+1)\pi/2$ and $x=n\pi$. The existence of the limit of the rations of derivatives is part of the assumptions of L'Hospital rule.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I know and agree with all the comments. I thought that there was something special about the solution since this question mentioned "Compute by common sense"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you calculate the derivative of the numerator and the denumerator, then you have $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{1-\sin x}{1+\cos x},$$ and this limit does not exist, since $\lim_{x \to \infty} \sin x$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} \cos x$ do not exist.

However, $\lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{x+\cos x}{x+\sin x} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{1+\frac{\cos x}{x}}{1+ \frac{\sin x}{x}} = 1$

Answer (score 1):

To show that L' Hopital's Rule doesn't work, just apply it. You get $\lim_{x  \to \infty} \frac{1 - \sin x}{1 + \cos x}$. Can you work that limit out? It may help to use a tangent half-angle substitution (Weierstrass substitution) to simplify that to a simple algebraic expression in terms of $\tan \frac x2$. Then it's even easier to see.

Remember L'Hopital's Rule depends on certain conditions. One of the conditions is the "reduced" limit actually exists. In this case, it doesn't.

To actually, work out the limit, the comments have already given you some great hints. Basically a simple bounding argument would work on top and bottom.